# Split a string at newline characters

Tags: python, string

I have a string, say

```
a = "Show  details1\nShow  details2\nShow  details3\nShow  details4\nShow  details5\n"
```

How do we split the above with the delimiter `\n` (a newline)?

The result should be

```
['Show  details1', 'Show  details2', ..., 'Show  details5']
```

Comment: do you want it to be ["show", "details1", "show", "details2", ... ] or ["show details1", "show details2", ... ]

Comment: Is it literally '\n', or is it a newline character?

Comment: @ezod: `\n` is a new-line character

Comment: @Hulk: where are you getting this line from?

Comment: I need it as ["show details1", "show details2", ... ]

Also i am getting the above line from a log....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are concerned only with the trailing newline, you can do:

```
a.rstrip().split('\n')
```

See, str.lstrip() and str.strip() for variations.

If you are more generally concerned by superfluous newlines producing empty items, you can do:

```
filter(None, a.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks @ddaa. It helped a lot

Answer (score 22):

Use `a.splitlines()`.  This will return you a list of the separate lines.  To get your "should be" result, add `" ".join(a.splitlines())`, and to get all in lower case as shown, the whole enchilada looks like `" ".join(a.splitlines()).lower()`.

Comment: Paul, I integrated info from the OP's comment to another answer.  He doesn't seem to want the "join" part of this...

Comment: @Idan, it's lots fast.  On my machine it splits the 10MB string 'test this\n'*int(1e6)` in 280ms or 28ns per char.  Do you have a performance problem involving this function?

Comment: @Peter - Thanks, no problems. Was just wondering since it does 2 passes on the original string (one for `splitlines` and another for `lower`) but I guess it doesn't change much.

Comment: This is a much better response then most answers to most questions of this kind, because it also works with windows style newlines.

Answer (score 6):

[`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
a.split('\n')[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 a.split('\n')
```

would return an empty entry as the last member of the list.so use

> `a.split('\n')[:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
a.split('\n')
```

Comment: This doesnt work. i get the result as
 ['Show  details', 'Show  details', '']

1 more element

Comment: So ignore the last element?  Your input string does have an empty string after the last \n.